# Send request parameters when calling a PHP script via command line

Tags: command-line, php

When you run a PHP script through a browser it looks something like

```
http://somewebsite.com/yourscript?param1=val1&param2=val2.
```

I am trying to achieve the same thing via command line without having to rewrite the script to accept `argv` instead of `$_REQUEST`. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
php yourscript.php?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

such that the parameters you send show up in the `$_REQUEST` variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to achieve that. The web server will split up the request string and pass it into the PHP interpreter, who will then store it in the `$_REQUEST` array.

If you run from the command line and you want to accept similar parameters, you'll have to parse them yourself. The command line has completely different syntax for passing parameters than HTTP has. You might want to look into [`getopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php).

For a brute force approach that doesn't take user error into account, you can try this snippet:

```
<?php
foreach( $argv as $argument ) {
        if( $argument == $argv[ 0 ] ) continue;

        $pair = explode( "=", $argument );
        $variableName = substr( $pair[ 0 ], 2 );
        $variableValue = $pair[ 1 ];
        echo $variableName . " = " . $variableValue . "\n";
        // Optionally store the variable in $_REQUEST
        $_REQUEST[ $variableName ] = $variableValue;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$ php test.php --param1=val1 --param2=val2
param1 = val1
param2 = val2
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something like that and it works well.

Answer (score 18):

In case you don't want to modify running script, you can specify parameters using in -B parameter to specify code to run before the input file. But in this case you must also add -F tag to specify your input file:

```
php -B "\$_REQUEST = array('param1' => 'val1', 'param2' => 'val2');" -F yourscript.php
```

Comment: $ needs to be escaped, otherwise your shell will substitute $_REQUEST, probably for an empty string and give the error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in Command line begin code on line 1

Comment: Doesn't work without escaping the $. This does: `php -B "\$_REQUEST = array('param1' => 'val1', 'param2' => 'val2');" -F yourscript.php`

Comment: It seems, this does not work (anymore?) with php 7.4 - using this command php command starts and hangs without anything returning.

Comment: you have to press enter two times

Comment: @ChristophLösch It hangs because `-F` will run the script file for every line from STDIN. `-f` will just run the script once, ignoring STDIN. `-F` is used here because it allows for the `-B` switch, which lets you specify code to run before processing STDIN. I wish there was a `-b` switch to specify begin block for `-f` too...

Answer (score 13):

I can't take credit for this but I adopted this in my bootstrap file:

```
// Concatenate and parse string into $_REQUEST
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
    parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_REQUEST);
}
```

Upon executing a PHP file from the command line:

```
php yourscript.php param1=val1 param2=val2
```

The above will insert the keys and values into $_REQUEST for later retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short function to handle this situation -- if command line arguments are present and the $_REQUEST array is empty (ie, when you're running a script from the command line instead of though a web interface), it looks for command line arguments in key=value pairs,

```
Argv2Request($argv);

print_r($_REQUEST);

function Argv2Request($argv) {
    /*
      When $_REQUEST is empty and $argv is defined,
      interpret $argv[1]...$argv[n] as key => value pairs
      and load them into the $_REQUEST array

      This allows the php command line to subsitute for GET/POST values, e.g.
      php script.php animal=fish color=red number=1 has_car=true has_star=false
     */


    if ($argv !== NULL && sizeof($_REQUEST) == 0) {
        $argv0 = array_shift($argv); // first arg is different and is not needed

        foreach ($argv as $pair) {
            list ($k, $v) = split("=", $pair);
            $_REQUEST[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

The sample input suggested in the function's comment is:

```
php script.php animal=fish color=red number=1 has_car=true has_star=false
```

which yields the output:

```
Array
(
    [animal] => fish
    [color] => red
    [number] => 1
    [has_car] => true
    [has_star] => false
)
```