# notice: undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR

Tags: php, sockets, xampp

I've been trying to follow [this](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket) tutorial and I did everything it said. I clicked the download button, installed XAMPP, copied the directory of the only server.php file i found, and put it in the following line, and ran it in the shell like it said.

php -q c:\xampp1\php\pear\adodb\server.php

But I got a bunch of warnings about files not being included and other stuff, which i don't understand because I downloaded everything it said and followed the tutorial. This is a screenshot of all my errors (I can't copy paste in xampp shell):

[image]

EDIT: Here is the server.php files code:

```
<?php

/** 
 * @version V4.93 10 Oct 2006 (c) 2000-2012 John Lim (jlim#natsoft.com). All rights reserved.
 * Released under both BSD license and Lesser GPL library license. 
  Whenever there is any discrepancy between the two licenses, 
  the BSD license will take precedence. 
 */

/* Documentation on usage is at http://php.weblogs.com/adodb_csv
 *
 * Legal query string parameters:
 * 
 * sql = holds sql string
 * nrows = number of rows to return 
 * offset = skip offset rows of data
 * fetch = $ADODB_FETCH_MODE
 * 
 * example:
 *
 * http://localhost/php/server.php?select+*+from+table&nrows=10&offset=2
 */


/* 
 * Define the IP address you want to accept requests from 
 * as a security measure. If blank we accept anyone promisciously!
 */
$ACCEPTIP = '127.0.0.1';

/*
 * Connection parameters
 */
$driver = 'mysql';
$host = 'localhost'; // DSN for odbc
$uid = 'root';
$pwd = 'garbase-it-is';
$database = 'test';

/*============================ DO NOT MODIFY BELOW HERE =================================*/
// $sep must match csv2rs() in adodb.inc.php
$sep = ' :::: ';

include('./adodb.inc.php');
include_once(ADODB_DIR.'/adodb-csvlib.inc.php');

function err($s)
{
    die('**** '.$s.' ');
}

// undo stupid magic quotes
function undomq(&$m) 
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        // undo the damage
        $m = str_replace('\\\\','\\',$m);
        $m = str_replace('\"','"',$m);
        $m = str_replace('\\\'','\'',$m);

    }
    return $m;
}

///////////////////////////////////////// DEFINITIONS


$remote = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 


if (!empty($ACCEPTIP))
 if ($remote != '127.0.0.1' && $remote != $ACCEPTIP) 
    err("Unauthorised client: '$remote'");


if (empty($_REQUEST['sql'])) err('No SQL');


$conn = ADONewConnection($driver);

if (!$conn->Connect($host,$uid,$pwd,$database)) err($conn->ErrorNo(). $sep . $conn->ErrorMsg());
$sql = undomq($_REQUEST['sql']);

if (isset($_REQUEST['fetch']))
    $ADODB_FETCH_MODE = $_REQUEST['fetch'];

if (isset($_REQUEST['nrows'])) {
    $nrows = $_REQUEST['nrows'];
    $offset = isset($_REQUEST['offset']) ? $_REQUEST['offset'] : -1;
    $rs = $conn->SelectLimit($sql,$nrows,$offset);
} else 
    $rs = $conn->Execute($sql);
if ($rs){ 
    //$rs->timeToLive = 1;
    echo _rs2serialize($rs,$conn,$sql);
    $rs->Close();
} else
    err($conn->ErrorNo(). $sep .$conn->ErrorMsg());

?>
```

I was going to google the errors but I think they are self explanatory, I just don't know why this code would give me includes when they aren't there and why it would give me parameters that aren't defined as in the final notice at the bottom of the screen cap. I'm guessing I have to put an IP address somewhere but I'm not sure where and if that's all. BTW I have a mysql database I can log into, I just don't know how to combine it with this.

How do I proceed in following this tutorial and get a running chat working?

(edit: I updated the screencap to reflect adding the 1 to xampp in the line but its mostly the same)

Comment: I have no immediate solution to your issue, nor do I have the setup to dig for the answer right now. But you realize that example is about 5 years old. It's highly likely that some libraries or dependencies have been updated in those 5 years and you will have to use the tutorial as more of a guide than gospel.

Comment: I guess use a different tutorial?  There are many from which to choose.  This reads more like a complaint that you found something on the internet that might not work rather than an answerable question about actual code.

Comment: i googled for more tutorials and found one but its litterally just a copy of this one. I don't know what other tutorials I can use to update a page with two users using sockets. and I was also wondering why it didn't work and if I could change something to fix it.

Comment: I added the code that the errors were about, so maybe the downvoters can see that this could be a decent question about code now...

Answer (score 13):

Because you're running PHP from the command line, there is no value in `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`. You should change that line to:

```
$remote = isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) ? $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] : '127.0.0.1';
```

or if you're using PHP7

```
$remote = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] ?? '127.0.0.1';
```

Comment: thanks, that fixed line 68. Do you have any idea how to take care of the include errors though?

Comment: It looks like all the include errors are because it can't find adodb.inc.php. Do you have an adodb.inc.php in the same directory as server.php?

Comment: Yes it's in there.

Comment: I think the problem is your `include`, according to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) because it has `./` at the beginning of the filename, it causes PHP to ignore the `include_path` and only look in the current directory (which looks to be `C:\xampp1`), which is not where the file is. Try changing the `include` to `include 'adodb.inc.php';`

Comment: that got rid of all the warnings. all that output was "No SQL". isn't a browser supposed to open? Not sure whats going on.

Comment: A browser won't open on its own. It looks like the code really wants to be run from a browser so you can set either `$_GET` or `$_POST`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513088/send-request-parameters-when-calling-a-php-script-via-command-line) shows a way to do that from the command line.